# Number in binary as a product

Tags: number-theory, binary, perfect-numbers

I agree that any binary number that consists of $n$ ones (and no zeros) has as its decimal equivalent the number $2^n - 1$. However, the author of the book I'm reading next makes the following claim, which I don't quite see. He says that as a consequence of the fact above, it follows that any binary number that has the form of starting with $n$ ones and ending with $n - 1$ zeros (with nothing between them) has as its decimal equivalent the number $2^{n - 1}(2^n - 1)$. For example, the decimal number 496 in binary is 111110000, which consists of five 1s followed by four 0s, so $496 = 2^4 \times (2^5 - 1) = 16 \times 31$. But why is this true, i.e. why does it work?

Comment: Multiply $11111_2$ by $10000_2$; do you agree that a binary number that consists of $1$ followed by $n$ zeros is $2^n$?

Comment: Imagine that it's base ten, and instead of ones, we have nines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your binary number starts with $n$ ones followed by $n-1$ zeros, the number has $n+(n-1) = 2n-1$ binary digits. Therefore its decimal value is
$$ 
\begin{align}
& 0 \times 2^{0} + 0 \times 2^{1} + \cdots + 0 \times 2^{n-2} + 1 \times 2^{n-1} + 1 \times 2^{n} + 1 \times 2^{n+1} + \cdots + 1 \times 2^{2n-3} +  1 \times 2^{2n-2}  \\
&= 2^{n-1} \left( 1 + 2 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^{n-2 } + 2^{n-1} \right) \\
&= 2^{n-1} \frac{1 - 2^n }{1 - 2 } \\
&= 2^{n-1} \frac{2^n - 1 }{2-1} \\
&= 2^{n-1} \left( 2^n-1 \right).
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it is easy to see in base$10$:  $$999990000 = 99999\times 10^4=(10^5-1)10^4$$
In base$2$:
$$(111110000)_2 = (11111)_2\times 2^4=(2^5-1)2^4$$

---

If you're not comfortable with base2, change it to base10:
$$\begin{align}(111110000)_2 &= 0+0+0+0+2^4+2^5+2^6+2^7+2^8 \\
&= 2^4(1+2+2^2+2^3+2^4) \\
&= 2^4(2^5-1)
\end{align}$$